Method of characteristics, the characteristic lines follow gradient, is this significant?
The PDE I am working on comes from geology, which I do not have much background on. 
Said equation aims to describe describes the erosion by describing it as an advection phenomena: the advection field however, depends only on the sum of upstream gradients. Can we say that it is still an advection equation type in this case?
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = u - k_f A^m \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}
$$
where

$u$ and $k_f$ are empirical constants and
the $A$ term is calculated separately (numerically) by accumulating the gradients, that is, every upstream point that reaches the current point.

If the characteristic lines follow the gradient, is this significant where it changes the type of the PDE?

Do you mean $A$ depends on certain integrals of $\nabla h$? Or are there multiple quantities being considered to be advected by the fields.
